# Set Least Significant Bit in C

Tags: c, bit, steganography, significant-digits

I write a simple steganography tool in C with bmp images.

I read the image to memory and the text to hide in char bytes[8] one character at a time.

so eg.

```
a=0d97
bytes[0] = 0
bytes[1] = 1
bytes[2] = 1
bytes[3] = 0
bytes[4] = 0
bytes[5] = 0
bytes[6] = 0
bytes[7] = 1
```

Then i 'll go to the first image byte(`char *ptr points` it every time) to put the bytes[0] to LSB, then the next one etc.

If the `*ptr=0xff or 0b11111111` i have to set the last 1 to 0. This can be with

```
*ptr = *ptr ^ 0x01 ;
```

but if the `*ptr = 0x00` or `0b00000000` the xor doesent work because `0^1=1`

I 'm confused how to set the case. I need a operator to make the last bit every time 0 and not touch the others in case LSB is 1 or 0.

Answer (score 10):

Use this pattern to set the least significant bit to the value in bit (0 or 1):

```
new_value = old_value & 0xFE | bit
```

The AND will turn off bit zero and the OR will turn it back on if bit is 1.

Answer (score 8):

The AND of 1 and x is x, while the AND of 0 and x is 0. So, AND it with a number with all bits set to 1 except for the least significant bit:

```
*ptr = *ptr & 0xfe;
```

To set the bit to 1, note that the OR of 0 and x is x, while the OR of 1 and x is 1:

```
*ptr = *ptr | 0x01;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `|` operator to set the bit. Check out the related post to see more details: [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

The most simple answer is.
If u want to set the lsb as zero in a number. 
If the number is odd,
Num=num-1.
If it is even,it already has zero at lsb.

Comment: This requires testing the current value. *Not* the most simple.